# Showing continuity at a point and solving integral.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I know that, in the problem below, $\int\limits_{-1}^{1}fd\alpha = f(0)$. How can infer this from the proof?

---

**Problem.** Let $f:[-1,1]\to R$ be a bounded function, $a,b,c\in R$ be such that $a<b<c$, and let $\alpha : R\to R$ be defined by
$$
 \alpha(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc} a & x<0 \\ b & x=0 \\ c & x>0 \end{array}\right. . 
$$ Show that if $f\in{R(\alpha)}$ on $[-1,1]$ then $f$ is continuous at $x=0$ and, in this case find the value of $\int\limits_{-1}^{1}fd\alpha$.

*Proof.* Suppose $f\in R(\alpha)$. Let $\varepsilon>0$. There exists a partition, say $P$, of $[-1,1]$ such that
$$
 U(P,f)-L(P,f)<\varepsilon\cdot\min(b-a,c-b).
$$
Let $P=\{x_{0},x_{1},...,x_{k},0,y_{1},...,y_{kr}\}$, where $-1=x_{0}<x_{1}<...<x_{k}<0<y_{1}<...<y_{r}=1$. Then the only terms in the difference of the sum $U(P,f)-L(P,f)$ that survive are precisely those corresponding to the subintervals $[x_{k},0]$ and $[0,y_{1}]$. Therefore
\begin{align*}
U(P,f)-L(P,f)&=\left(\sup_{y\in[x_{k},0]}f(y)-\inf_{y\in[x_{k},0]}f(y)\right)\left(b-a\right)\\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad+\left(\sup_{y\in[0,y_{1}]}f(y)-\inf_{y\in[0,y_{1}]}f(y)\right)\left(c-b\right)\\
\quad&<\varepsilon\cdot\min\left(b-a,c-b\right).
\end{align*}
Thus, in particular,
$$
\left(\sup_{y\in[x_{k},0]}f(y)-\inf_{y\in[x_{k},0]}f(y)\right)\left(b-a\right)<\varepsilon\cdot\min\left(b-a,c-b\right)
.$$
Hence $$\sup_{y\in[x_{k},0]}f(y)-\inf_{y\in[x_{k},0]}f(y)<\varepsilon\quad\text{and similarly}\quad\sup_{y\in[0,y_{1}]}f(y)-\inf_{y\in[0,y_{1}]}f(y)<\varepsilon.$$
Now $0\in (x_{k},y_{1})$, the latter is an open neighborhood of $0$ and, if $a\in(x_{k},y_{1})$, then
$$
|f(a)-f(0)|\le\max\left(\sup_{y\in[x_{k},0]}f(y)-\inf_{y\in[x_{k},0]}f(y),\sup_{y\in[0,y_{1}]}f(y)-\inf_{y\in[0,y_{1}]}f(y)\right)<\varepsilon.
$$
Taking $\delta=\min(x_{k},y_{1})$, we see that if $|a|<\delta$ then $|f(a)-f(0)|<\varepsilon.$ Therefore, since epsilon was arbitrarily chosen, $f$ is continuous at $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the partition $P=\{-1,x_1,0,x_2,1\}.$ Then, $U(f,P,\alpha)=M_1(b-a)+M_2(c-b)$ and $L(f,P,\alpha)=m_1(b-a)+m_2(c-b)$ where $M_i,m_i:1\le i\le2$ are the maxima (resp. minima) of $f$ on the corresponding subintervals determined by $P.$ Then, $U(f,P,\alpha)-L(f,P,\alpha)=b(M_1-m_1)+a(M_2-m_2).$ Now as $x_1\to 0^-$ and $x_2\to 0^+$ continuity of $f$ at $0$ implies that $M_i-m_i\to 0.$ It follows that $f$ is integrable.

Now, let $\epsilon>0$. Choose $\delta>0$ such that $|x-0|<\delta\Rightarrow |f(x)-f(0)|<\epsilon.$ Then, if $P$ is as above and $|x_i|<\delta: 1\le i\le 2$, we have

$U(P,f,\alpha)-f(0)(c-a)=M_1(b-a)+M_2(c-b)-f(0)(c-b+b-a)=$

$(M_1-f(0))(b-a)+(M_2-f(0))(c-b)=\epsilon(c-a).$ It follows that $\int_{-1}^1fd\alpha=f(0)(c-a).$